# How to change the spelling checker on the fly?

Tags: settings, language

When I change the keyboard language, the spelling checker is not updated. I've to go to prefs, keyboard etc. to change it. Is there a better way?

Ideally I'd like it to change automatically when changing the keyboard language (seems logical?). I've to switch constantly between languages during the day, and this going to fiddle with the settings each time is super tedious.

Comment: Which version of MacOS? Probably [related thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231907/how-do-i-use-spell-check-in-osx-with-several-languages).

Comment: @slartibartfast 12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOS (unlike iOS) has never had the system spellcheck determined by the keyboard layout, it is always governed independently.  But some apps with their own spellcheck, like Word, will do this.

To switch spellcheck via a keyboard shortcut, see this [earlier answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300949/how-to-change-the-spelling-language-in-os-x-with-applescript).

Comment: Ok thanks, and.. this needs scripting, really? Apple doesn't think much about internationalization apparently.

Comment: @User Apple's language support does tend to be hit and miss.  Their "multilingual" spellcheck system, mentioned in the "related thread" comment on your question,  may work ok for some users.